# App cache with google map API

Tags: html, caching, google-api

I am creating the HTML5 mobile application and right now i have some problem in app caching , in my application i am showing the google map on my pages but i do not want to add the google api in app caching , but when i do not add the google api in app cache manifest file the application dont run , chrome show me this error

`can not get:- http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/8/%7Bcommon,util%7D.js`

`can not get:- http://maps.google.com/maps/api/jsv2/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FmmtFinal%2Ftrunk%2F&4sAIzaSyA4H0NCYZ49_bwl9AkwViEGzU3gEen7-4I&5e0&callback=_xdc_._0h4avmibb&token=15142`

I am clueless right now, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is the version of your google maps api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved it by not adding google maps api in app cache

Answer (score -1):

Try using Google Maps API v3.
I think you have a problem with you link to your api.
This should be the link in v3:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">        
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">        
</script> and i used the sensor=false as well but no success

Comment: anyone knows this problem? please help me out